# Корректно ли считать shell языком по умолчанию для меток [linux], [unix]?

Tags: обсуждение, метки

Множество вопросов и ответов по [linux](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux), [unix](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unix) и прочим *nix-системам включают в себя фрагменты скриптов на [shell](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shell) и производных от него языках. Но соответствующая метка ставится не всегда.

Стоит ли выставить lang-sh как язык по умолчанию для меток *nix-ОС? Плюс в том, что мы получим более адекватную подсветку синтаксиса в вопросах. Потенциальный минус — неверная подсветка, когда используются метки с разными языками. Хотя [пример вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/137478/181472) по [c](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) & [linux](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux) показывает, что используется язык от более популярной метки и подстветка синтаксиса адекватна.

Картинка кликабельна.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я прошвырнулся по вопросам, и у меня впечатление, что у вопросов, которые касаются Linux, но не касаются shell-языков, содержат в блоках кода скорее **фрагменты логов** и **конфиги**, которые в подобной подсветке **не нуждаются**.

Если уж в вопросе речь о шелл-скриптах, лучше добавить к нему метку [shell](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shell), [bash](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash), [sh](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sh), или что там подходит лучше. Правильные метки у вопросов это важно.